# HTMX + Flask Active search with pagination

Tags: flask, pagination, full-text-search, htmx

I'm trying to add pagination to HTMX Active Search.

this is my base code example:

view:

```
@app.route('/search_items', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def search_items():
   #some forms here
   users = User.query.all()
   items = Item.query.all()

   templ = """
   #table template goes here
   """

   searchWord = flask.request.form.get('search_items', None)
   matches = [item for item in items if item.search_items(searchWord)]
   return flask.render_template_string(templ,
   items=matches,
   users=users,
   )
```

html_template:

```
<input class="form-control"
    type="search_items"
    name="search_items"
    placeholder="Begin Typing To Search Item..."
    hx-post="/search_items"
    hx-trigger="load, keyup changed delay:500ms, search"
    hx-target="#search_items-results"
    hx-indicator=".htmx-indicator">

<table class="table table-hover table-dark table-layout:fixed margin-top:10px" id="search_items-results">
</table>
```

and this is works fine.

I have literally no idea where to start.
I will by grateful for any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.